# I wanna get hard disk serial code in unity but it makes NotImplementedException

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hard-drive

So here is the problem: I wanna get the hard disk serial code by using unity 2020.3, so I used the code:

```
using System.Management;

public string GetHarddiskSerial()
{
    string serial_number = "";
        
    **ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive");**
    // This line makes error

    foreach (ManagementObject wmi_HD in searcher.Get())
    {
        serial_number = wmi_HD["SerialNumber"].ToString();
        Console.WriteLine("Harddisk Serial : " + serial_number);
    }
    return serial_number;
}
```

However, it occured error and could not play.

> NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.
> System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher..ctor (System.String queryString) (at :0)
> (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher..ctor(string)

I tried find System.Management.dll and put it in (Project Name)/Assets/Plugin Folder, but it didn't work.

Secondly, I put the dll in C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2020.3.9f1\Editor\Data\Mono\lib\mono\2.0 too.

My final goal is getting hard disk serial code in unity, so if you have a solution that can get serial code, please tell me.

Comment: `NotImplementedException` sounds pretty self-explanatory ... might be that this method is not supported on all target platforms

Comment: So does that mean this is not possible in Unity?

Comment: It means it is no possible on the device/OS you are running this on

Answer (score 0):

You will need to call an application outside of Unity to run these queries (on windows) using `System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processwindowstyle?view=net-7.0

I suspect mono does not implement windows specific things, given it's nature.